# Is it possible to provide multiple constraints as type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have the following situation:

```
public class SomeClass {/*… */}
public interface ISomeInterface {/*… */}

public T GetFirst<T>(){/*… gets the first object of type T */}
public void AddElement<T> () where T: SomeClass, ISomeInterface {/*… */}
```

What I would like to do is call GetFirst with the Type parameter being anything that derives from both SomeClass and ISomeInterface.

As an example, if I had the following classes:

```
class A : SomeClass, ISomeInterface { }
class B : SomeClass, ISomeInterface { }
class C : SomeClass, ISomeInterface { }
```

And I want to specify the type parameter of GetFirst() to return any of A, B, or C, so the result could satisfy the type constraint of AddElement:

```
void MyFunction()
{
    t result = GetFirst<t>() where t : SomeClass, ISomeInterface;
    AddElement(result);
}
```

Is it possible to define multiple type constraints when supplying a type parameter in C#?

Comment: You've already got that constraint for `AddElement` - I'm not sure why you're not just applying that to `GetFirst`...

Comment: That's not a type constraint, that's a type.  You can only supply one.

Comment: @JonSkeet He's talking about a situation where you want all the items that satisfy both constraints, not modifying what types GetFirst<T>() can return.  Like if I wanted all the objects from a list which implement both IComparable<T> and IEnumerable<T>, there's no way to specify that as a caller to the type parameters.

Comment: @BryceWagner: If that's the case, then `GetFirst` shouldn't be generic at all. Fundamentally I think the question is unclear at the moment - I *suspect* the OP has misunderstood generics, but without more information it's going to be hard to know exactly what the misunderstanding is, or how to help them.

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly Brice Wagner said.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage example you've provided would only be possible if:

1. you have a known type that you're expecting to provide, or
2. C# supported [intersection types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/399) (e.g., [like TypeScript does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)).

`#1` might look like this:

```
void MyFunction()
{
    KnownType result = GetFirst<KnownType>();
    AddElement(result);
}

public class KnownType: SomeClass, ISomeInterface {...}

public T GetFirst<T>() => this.objects.OfType<T>().First();
```

`#2` isn't currently possible because C# doesn't have intersection types.